# Способы передачи файла через компорт(Comport, rs232)

Tags: c++, rs232, com-port

Здравствуйте, необходимо реализовать передачу файла на comport. Объясните, пожалуйста, если компорт ведет дело с байтами, то задача "Передать файл" сводится к побайтовой передачи нужного файла?  [image: Пример теримана]

Comment: Картинка говорит о том, что передавать файл требуется с помощью программы "Terminal"? В целом да, файл - набор байтов, последовательный порт позволяет передавать байты последовательно.

Comment: Ой, забыл добавить. На картинке пример отправки файла по кнопке(SendFile в секции Transmit). Мне нужно реализовать нечто подобное. К сожалению, спросить у преподавателя не могу, а собственные догадки сводятся к побайтовой передачи файла.

Comment: Программа Terminal передаёт файл как он есть. Но вам в своей реализации ничто не мешает снабдить его каким-то заголовком. Например, добавить маркер начала передачи файла, размер файла, контрольную сумму, а уже потом отправлять сам файл побайтно.